# Issues with WIFI Authentification pages

Tags: wifi, backup, time-machine, keychain, authentication

I realized yesterday that I could not see authentification pages of some WIFI. I'm running High Sierra 10.13.

Apparently to solve this issue I have to go to Keychain Access > Preferences > Certificates => disable OCSP and CRL.

The problem is that "Certificates" panel doesn't exist anymore.

Some people said that I had to find an old version of keychain.menu (TimeMachine's backup) but I don't have an old backup.

Could someone please update their old version of keychain.menu or help me one way or another to disable OCSP and CRL?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add your answer as a proper answer below so that others can see the answer and vote on it. The question is just meant to contain the question!

Comment: write your solution as an answer and you might get points for it

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know, thank you very much both of you !

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

I had to remove all DNS and empty my DNS cache.

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use terminal and try this

To set the CRL settings:

```
defaults write com.apple.security.revocation CRLStyle -string BestAttempt
```

To set the OCSP settings:

```
defaults write com.apple.security.revocation OCSPStyle -string BestAttempt
```

**However**..the WiFi authentication pages are not handled by Certificates.

The first step system does is to use the DNS to translate the "name" you gave to correct code (the IP address of your WiFi).
Once the "contact" is established the WiFi sends the authentication pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I fixed the issue in an other way and edited my post.

Comment: @Alais so nothing to do with certificates :) just simple DNS

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am sorry ;)